# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution (Flutter)

Tags: java, android, flutter, visual-studio-code, java-11

Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip'.

org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.

Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.\nYour current JDK is located in  C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Foundation\\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\\jre\nYou can try some of the following options:

- changing the IDE settings.
- changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
- changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

I tried changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable to "C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot", and also tried "F1" then JAVA: Install New JDK and install "OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.18_10", I even deleted all java related programs from the control panel uninstall except "Eclipse temurin JDK with Hotspot 11.0.18+10(x64)" and "java(TM) SE Development Kit 11.0.17 (64-bit)" ... NOTE: I am using flutter on VS code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set `java.configuration.runtimes` in vscode, configured it to *java 11*.

  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects

  ***example:***

  ```json
  "java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
      "name": "JavaSE-11",
      "path": "/usr/local/jdk-11.0.3",
      "sources" : "/usr/local/jdk-11.0.3/lib/src.zip",
      "javadoc" : "https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api",
      "default":  true
     },
  ]
  ```
- Set `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`,

  ```
  org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot
  ```

  *Make sure it is the correct java 11 installation path.*